# Integrated Windows Authentication with ADFS

Tags: adfs

In `SAML` implementation, I am able to send request to the ADFS server (`<server_name>/adfs/ls` ). It should redirect to  authentication sign in page (`<server_name>/adfs/ls/auth/integrated`). But its not taking to Single Sign on page.

I have checked the `web.config` file, windows authentication moved at the top.

```
<microsoft.identityServer.web>
    <localAuthenticationTypes>
      <add name="Integrated" page="auth/integrated/" />
      <add name="Forms" page="FormsSignIn.aspx" />
      <add name="TlsClient" page="auth/sslclient/" />
      <add name="Basic" page="auth/basic/" />
    </localAuthenticationTypes>
    <commonDomainCookie writer="" reader="" />
    <context hidden="true" />
    <error page="Error.aspx" />
    <acceptedFederationProtocols saml="true" wsFederation="true" />
    <homeRealmDiscovery page="HomeRealmDiscovery.aspx" />
    <persistIdentityProviderInformation enabled="true" lifetimeInDays="30" />
    <singleSignOn enabled="true" />
  </microsoft.identityServer.web>
```

I am not sure what I have missed here. I am invoking `SAML` Request from SP running Coldfusion app to ADFS.